# Effect not correctly drawn

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

We are currently working on a desktop app using wpf and mvvm. We need to show tool windows and other dialogs. To focus user attention to the active window the main app is blurred with a blur effect (Property Binding to ViewModel).

Here is a very basic draft of the implementation:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window
    ...
    Effect={Binding WindowEffect}
>

<Window.DataContext>
    <viewmodels:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

[... Content...]

</Window>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs:

```
SomeMethod() {
WindowEffect = new BlurEffect();
...
[retrieve data from server]
...
[create & show tool window]
...
WindowEffect = null;
}
```

This approach basically works, but bears some problems.
I am aware that it doesn't properly fullfil the mvvm pattern, since we are controlling UI directly through the ViewModel.
The actual problem is that the BlurEffect only comes into effect, when the tool window is shown. That we know since data retrieval from the server does take a couple of seconds...
Additionally the BlurEffect is only vislible, if the tool window is shown. If we substitute the dialog with some delay (Task.Delay) no blur is visible.

My question is how to properly handle this kind of approach?

Comment: You should use a datatrigger to apply the effect and bind to a bool rather than a ui component.

Answer (score 1):

Create a bool property in your VM:

```
// I am using Prism.Mvvm.BindableBase
public bool IsBlur
{
   get {return _isBlur;}
   set {SetProperty(ref _isBlur, value);}
}
```

In your Xaml,

```
<Window ....> <!--remove the Effect-->
<Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsBlur, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <BlurEffect .../> <!-- set some property here as necessary -->
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Style>
```

So, what you need to do is

```
IsBlur = true; // to turn on the blur effect
// or
IsBlur = false; // to turn off the blur effect
```

======== UPDATE ==========

So, I guess you are asking when you should turn on/off the blur effect. Generally, you should set the BlurEffect in 2 different places:

1. During window initialization (in constructor or Loaded event handler), set the IsBlur=true to begin with.
2. In your [retrieve data from server] method, you need to have this as a async Task, when it finishes, it should update the IsBlur=false.

Regarding how long, it depends on how long the [retrieve data from server] takes to complete. I don't think this is something that you should delay. If you really need to delay, then simply put delay on the [retrieve data from server].

Comment: Thank you for the example. But I could not get it to work. The blur effect is only shown at the moment I display a UserControl. Tested this with some delays before showing the other UserControl.

Comment: Sorry, if I didn't give the answer you needed. I just updated the answer and gave you the idea how to solve. Because, I don't think I can solve this with limited info you provided.

Comment: New comment, since last one could not be edited anymore: Hopefully this will make things more clear: [retrieve data from server] in my original post does take some time (about 2-5s) and the BlurEffect does only come into effect, when the [create & show tool window] part is executed. Therefore I have a delay that I can not get rid of. To test this I used some Thread.Sleep() because I did not have connection to the server at all times. My Question is how to get rid of the show delay from IsBlur=true to [create & show tool window]?